# Why can't Form Recognizer SDK v3 find any OCR documents to train?

Tags: .net, sdk, ocr, azure-form-recognizer

I am trying to build a Form Recognizer custom model using the v3 [preview](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer/4.0.0-beta.1/index.html), using the sample code:

```
Uri trainingFileUri = new Uri(sasToken);
var client = new DocumentModelAdministrationClient(
               new Uri(endpoint), new 
               AzureKeyCredential(apiKey));

BuildModelOperation operation = await client.StartBuildModelAsync(trainingFileUri);

Response<DocumentModel> operationResponse = await operation.WaitForCompletionAsync();
```

The sas token is a for a Blob container containing 20 pdf files. When I run I get the error

> Status: 200 (OK)
> ErrorCode: InvalidRequest
>
> Additional Information:
> AdditionInformation: InvalidRequest: Invalid request.
>
> Details:
> ModelBuildError: Could not build the model: Can't find any OCR files for training.
>
> Raw:
>
> {
> "code": "InvalidRequest",
> "message": "Invalid request.",
> "details": [
> {
> "code": "ModelBuildError",
> "message": "Could not build the model: Can\u0027t find any OCR files for training."
> }
> ]   }

The SAS token has read, write, list, etc permissions, so I don't know why the client could not find any documents to train. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preview API you linked to does not support training without labels. You will need a labeled dataset to train a model.

Did you use the [Form Recognizer Studio](https://formrecognizer.appliedai.azure.com/studio/) to label your files?

Training a model requires your storage account to contain 3 types of files:

1. A single file - fields.json
2. For each file in your training dataset 2 additional files are created during the labeling process

   - {FileName}.labels.json
   - {FileName}.ocr.json

The error message indicates that you may not have labeled your documents.

Comment: Thanks, I had labelled the dataset, but with v2 hence the fail. Thanks!